# Delphi pointer casting

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, casting

I want to use this simple C function in delphi, but cant cast the values to pointer perfectly.

C function :

```
PVOID GetInterfaceMethod(PVOID intf, DWORD methodIndex)
{
  return *(PVOID*)(*(DWORD_PTR*)intf + methodIndex);
}
```

Delphi function :

```
function GetInterfaceMethod(const intf; methodIndex: DWORD): Pointer;
begin
  // return *(PVOID*)(*(DWORD_PTR*)intf + methodIndex);    x64
  // return *(PVOID*)(*(DWORD*)intf + methodIndex * 4);    x86
  Result := Pointer(Pointer(DWORD_PTR(Pointer(intf)^) + methodIndex)^);  //x64
end;
```

Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: The x64 implementation is obviously wrong when looking at the x86 implementation (the commented code in the Delphi routine). So the C function in question might be wrong to begin with (if should multiply by 8). That would also make sense since the argument is called methodIndex and not byteOffset or something like that which then would by architecture dependant on the caller side.

Comment: `return *(PVOID*)(*(DWORD_PTR*)intf + methodIndex*sizeof(PVOID));` would work everywhere, although it would be a pretty lame way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a 100% translation of the C code but it does what you are trying to achieve by using this method:

```
  function GetInterfaceMethod(const intf; methodIndex: Cardinal): Pointer;
  type
    PPVtable = ^PVtable;
    PVtable = ^TVtable;
    TVtable = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(Pointer) - 1] of Pointer;
  begin
    Result := PPVtable(intf)^^[methodIndex];
  end;
```

This code illustrates the fact that an interface reference is a pointer to the IMT as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
PVOID GetInterfaceMethod(PVOID intf, DWORD methodIndex)
{
  return *(PVOID*)(*(DWORD_PTR*)intf + methodIndex);
}
```

To decode this we need to understand [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The highest precedence operator here is the type cast. Then dereference is higher than binary addition. So with added parens the expression becomes:

```
*(PVOID*)((*(DWORD_PTR*)intf) + methodIndex)
```

That is:

- cast `intf` to be pointer to `DWORD_PTR`,
- dereference that, to `DWORD_PTR`,
- add methodIndex,
- cast to pointer to `PVOID`,
- dereference that.

Note that this function is rather odd in that `methodIndex` is a byte offset rather than an array index. At best the parameter name is very misleading. At worst, it makes the function exceedingly hard to use, especially if you want code that will work independently from pointer size. So, I'd be surprised if this function is really the best way to solve whatever problem you are actually facing.

A literal translation goes like this:

```
function GetInterfaceMethod(intf: Pointer; byteOffset: DWORD): Pointer;
begin
  Result := PPointer(PDWORD_PTR(intf)^ + byteOffset)^;
end;
```

---

You might prefer to write this code where `methodIndex` is an array index rather than a byte offset. That would make way more sense. The C code would be:

```
PVOID GetInterfaceMethod(PVOID intf, DWORD methodIndex)
{
    return *(*(PVOID**)intf + methodIndex);
}
```

And the matching Delphi code:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
function GetInterfaceMethod(intf: Pointer; methodIndex: DWORD): Pointer;
begin
  Result := (PPointer(intf^) + methodIndex)^;
end;
```

Note very carefully that this function behaves quite differently from the one above because `methodIndex` is interpreted as an array index. So, this function is not a translation of the C code in the question.